# How to use multiple output formatters in one printf statement?

Tags: java, printf

EDIT: I apologize for the unclear question, I tried one of your answers and it worked perfectly. To add some clarity I was trying to print the oddNum, then the evenNum, and then the numSqred on one line for each loop iteration. I needed all three variables to be rounded to 4 decimal places with an even amount of whitespace between each variable. Thanks for the help!

I'm trying to write a printf statement that adds whitespace and rounds the double to four decimal places. I'm just not sure how I would format the printf statement to allow for both "%-10s" and "%.4f" for the one variable. Thank you for your help!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int NUM_RANGE = 86;      //allows for [0,176] range in loop output
        int i;                         //iteration index
        double oddNum = 1.0000;        //initialized as first odd num possible
        double evenNum = 0.0000;       //initialized as first even num possible
        double numSqred = Math.sqrt(oddNum + evenNum);
        
        System.out.printf("%-10s",oddNum);    //prints initial odd num
        System.out.printf("%-10s", evenNum);   //prints initial even num
        System.out.printf("%.4f \n" ,numSqred);
        
        for (i = 0; i < NUM_RANGE; ++i) {
            //updates oddNum to next odd number for each iteration
            oddNum += 2;                     
            System.out.printf("%-10s",oddNum); 
            //updates evenNum to next odd number for each iteration
            evenNum += 2;
            System.out.printf("%-10s", evenNum);
            //update numSqred for new odd and even num
            numSqred = Math.sqrt(oddNum + evenNum);
            System.out.printf("%.4f \n" ,numSqred);
        }
```

I tried separating the "%-10s" and "%.4f" by comma and by '+' and expected them both to apply the formatting to the one variable, but it didn't work. I've tried looking up how to do this but I haven't found anything so far.

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear, but, maybe you mean: Try `%-10.4f`?

Comment: Or do you mean something like `.printf("%-10s %-10s %.4f %n",oddNum, evenNum, numSqured );`

Comment: A agree: The question isn't quite clear. If the preceding comments haven't helped, perhaps you could edit the question to show some examples.

Comment: Could you edit your question to show the output you are seeing and the desired output please?

Answer (score 0):

> *'... I'm just not sure how I would format the printf statement to allow for both "%-10s" and "%.4f" for the one variable. ...'*

You can provide the *width* value.

```
%[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion
```

```
%-10.4f
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
System.out.printf("%-10.4f %-10.4f %-10.4f%n", oddNum, evenNum, numSqred);
```

as in:

```
final int NUM_RANGE = 86;      //allows for [0,176] range in loop output
double oddNum = 1.0000;        //initialized as first odd num possible
double evenNum = 0.0000;       //initialized as first even num possible
double numSqred = Math.sqrt(oddNum + evenNum);
String format = "%-10.4f %-10.4f %-10.4f%n";
System.out.printf(format, oddNum, evenNum, numSqred);
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_RANGE; i++) {
    //updates oddNum to next odd number for each iteration
    oddNum += 2;                     
    //updates evenNum to next odd number for each iteration
    evenNum += 2;
    //update numSqred for new odd and even num
    numSqred = Math.sqrt(oddNum + evenNum);
    System.out.printf(format, oddNum, evenNum, numSqred);
}
```